# How to create an index on the Date portion of a DateTime in EF Core 5?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm trying to set create an index on the `Date` component of a `System.DateTime` using the Fluent API in Entity Framework Core 5:

```
builder.Entity<Trade>()
        .HasIndex(x => x.TradeDateTime.Date);
```

However, I receive the following error when attempting to add the migration:

```
System.ArgumentException: The expression 'x => Convert(x.TradeDateTime.Date, Object)' is not a valid member access expression. The expression should represent a simple property or field access: 't => t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties or fields, use an anonymous type: 't => new { t.MyProperty, t.MyField }'. (Parameter 'memberAccessExpression')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show DDL SQL which is expected?

Comment: Why don't you want to just index the TradeDateTime attribute, including the time? That index would still be useful for date criteria or ranges.

Comment: I think it's because it's not common to put an index on `DateTime` column; The index tree will become so large if you include `Time` too